# App crashes when run from phone but works fine when launched from computer

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, null

I've been able after 3 days of work to make an old app run on my device! But only when the command comes from my computer...

I explain. When I launch the app from Android Studio on my phone, it launches fine, which is great. But when I launch it directly from my phone, I get in Catlog that a String is null. I don't understand what could cause this.. It works fine when the app is started from my computer but not from the phone...

Please, help!

**Edit 1**: Add AndroidManifest.xml activities

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ManageAccountActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".RegionListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ClubListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".TeetimesListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ConfirmationActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".TermsAndConditionsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".TabletSearchActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".TabletConfirmationActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity"/>
```

**Edit 2**: Error log

```
01-08 16:08:47.194 26704-26704/ca.gggolf.aminutegolf E/ACRA: ACRA caught a RuntimeException for ca.gggolf.aminutegolf
                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.gggolf.aminutegolf/ca.gggolf.aminutegolf.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                             at ca.gggolf.aminutegolf.LoginActivity.checkForNewBooking(LoginActivity.java:676)
                                                             at ca.gggolf.aminutegolf.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:112)
                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

**Edit 3**: Add a part of the code containing the errors

```
private void checkForNewBooking() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        final String numConfirmation = extras.getString("NEWLY_BOOKED");
        final String date[] = extras.getString("BOOKING_DATE").split("-"); //line 676
        final String time[] = extras.getString("BOOKING_TIME").split(":");
        final String club = extras.getString("BOOKING_CLUB");
        final int hole = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("BOOKING_HOLE"));
```

**Edit 4**: More code. Here is the onCreate() method. The call for the method checkForNewBooking() comes from there.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    mController = new ActivityController(this);

    // Setting server mode
    ((Globals) getApplication()).setServerInformation(SharedPrefManager.getServer(this));

    // Hide auto-triggered keyboard
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    if (SharedPrefManager.isFirstRun(LoginActivity.this)) {
        SharedPrefManager.setFirstTimePrefs(LoginActivity.this, Utility.retreiveLanguage());
        Log.d(TAG, "First run triggered.");
    }

    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (mBundle != null) {
        if (mBundle.getBoolean("PROCESS_KILLED")) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.ui_error_killedprocess, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            checkForNewBooking();
        }
    }
    initializeUI();

    WrappedLogger.setProvider(new LoggingProvider());
    WrappedLogger.setMemoryLog(false);
    IPAddressInformation.getInstance().getIPAddress();
}
```

Comment: please include at least you manifest activity declarations and the run configuration you use on your computer to start the app

Comment: Are the emulator and the device using the same operating system?

Comment: The Run config is the defaultest it can be. Deploy and launch are set to default with no install flags or launch flags. For the emulator, I'm not running any, from the computer, it boots on my device directly.

Comment: Hi @dequec64, please post the full stacktrace of the error log.

Comment: Please post LoginActivity.java and indicate which line is 676.

Comment: Okay, now post the code for the `Intent` that you set up with `"BOOKING_DATE"` and call this activity

Comment: please post more code

Comment: where do you put the extras for LoginActivity ? also why is your launcher activity expecting extras in the intent ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you setup the extras of the `Intent` passed to `LoginActivity`?
I would anyhow suggest that you use `intent.hasExtra()` method to ensure that all extras are passed and log an event in case of missing extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not a complete great super answer, but I've been able to fix this bug simply by changing the first if statement in the checkForNewBooking().
Now it is:

```
if(extras.getString("BOOKING_DATE") != null)
```

instead of

```
if(extras != null)
```

I seriously don't know why the program started with this.. The class I posted parts of is the main one, launching at the start and so information don't come from there. According to the comments the guy before me left, this method is meant to check if a booking has been completed in the past, meaning maybe that the information required for BOOKING_DATE and BOOKING_TIME comes from another method once a booking has been completed.

Anyway, it works now! Thank you all for the help!